# What are these files in my "~/Library/Safari/" folder?

Tags: finder, safari, macos

So, I was messing with this folder and while doing this I turned show hidden files on and saw some strange files. These are the names of them, and sizes

```
.dat8ad4.007 (733K)
.dat011e.000 (704K)
.dat1267.003 (402K)
.dat2eb2.06d (396 Byte)
```

The top files are hex files, and the last one is some weird encoded text and a link to a youtube channel. What are these files?

Comment: FWIW: My Safari folder does not contain files like that. Which OSX?

Comment: Are they directly in `~/Library/Safari`? All I get is `.DS_Store`.

Comment: Im using Yosemite, but some of the files are very old, older than 5 years.

Comment: I suspect that you'd be fine just deleting them.

Comment: @dougggro yeah I know, but I'm more interested as to what they are.

Comment: Could be remnants of an old plugin or add-on for Safari that left their cruft in those hidden files.